# Copy a Different Program's Local Server (Java)

Tags: java

First off, networking is not my strongest subject. So sorry if this question is ridiculous, or if I'm missing some major information. I'd be happy to provide any needed.

I am trying spoof a server program. The program I am trying to pretend to be basically creates a local server, then allows client versions of the same program to connect (provided they are on the same computer).
Using `netstat -a -b -n` I was able to figure out that the server was binding itself to `0.0.0.0:53640`. The other information given was:

- Proto: UDP
- Local Address: 0.0.0.0:56426
- Foreign Address: * : * (Without spaces, stackoverflow doesn't seem to like this when it doesn't have them)
- State: (Was blank)

The closest I was able to come was

- Proto: TCP
- Local Address: 0.0.0.0:56426
- Foreign Address: 0.0.0.0:0
- State: LISTENING

The code that I am using is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String ip = "0.0.0.0";
        int port = 53640;

        try
        {   
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port, 5, address);
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Got connection!");
            doSocket(socket);
            server.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void doSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Connection from: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            int b;
            char c;

            while ((b = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                c = (char) b;
                System.out.print(c);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`ServerSocket.accept` seems to never stop yielding, as "Got connection!" is never printed to the output.
All help is very welcome. Thanks in advance! And sorry if I've done something horribly wrong with this post, its my first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP is connection-less, and 'ServerSocket' is connection-oriented and TCP-only. Have a look at the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/) on datagrams (UDP).

UDP ports and TCP ports are in different namespaces; you can't get mixups from one to the other.